# How to render a view from a view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm try to initialize a view onload and then attach an event listener to a link in the initial view such that when someone clicks that link, the document body is replaced with a different backbone.js view.

I'm pretty close, but I keep running into a js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined underscore-min.js:5
```

Secondarily, how can I add a class to #container within #blog once the view is rendered? You'll see in the fiddle that I've already got the CSS and new class written up.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdsYc/)

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/template" id="index">
    <a href="" id="thing">click here</a>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="blog">
    <div id="container"><p>Hello world.</p></div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
    BlogView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){},
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template( $("#blog").html(), {} );
            this.$el.html( template );
        }
    });

    IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function () {
          this.render();
      },
      render: function () {
          var template = _.template($("#index").html(), {});
          this.$el.html(template);
      },
      events: {
          "click a": "initBlogView"
      },
      initBlogView: function () {
          blog_view.render();
          return false;
      }
  });

  var blog_view = new BlogView({ el: $("body") });

  var index_view = new IndexView({
      el: $("body")
  });
```

Secondarily, I would l

Comment: Not really related to your question, but it's generally a good practice to add `return this;` at the end of your render.

Comment: Do you mean inside of InitBlogView I should return this? I'm returning false, otherwise, clicking on the link will return and cause an error.

Comment: No, I mean actually in the render function after `this.$el.html(template);`. It's just a good practice to return the view you're rendering in your render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with targeting "body" is that you're also overwriting your script template markup.  Underscore can't find the templates after that, resulting in the error.  Try targeting a container instead.

To add a class, you can use simply `this.$el.find("#container").addClass("class")`.

[Here's the updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/J5kHF/2/)

Comment: Yup, that definitely makes sense. How about my other question re: adding a class to #container within #blog once the view is rendered?

Comment: @doremi I thought I answered that part (2nd paragraph)?